# 'void' as generic parameter

Tags: .net, generics

I have function that do common stuff:

```
class MyBaseClass<TOut> 
{
    public abstract TOut MyFunc<TOut>();
}
```

and particular implementations

```
class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass<string> 
{
    public override string MyFunc<string>()
    {
        string strSomeThing;
        ... initialization of strSomeThing;
        return strSomeThing;
    }
}
```

and few similar derived classes.

(There are no any restrictions on generic type).

Today I got case when I need 'MyFunc' to do some actions (let's say save data in DB) and do NOT need to return anything meaningful...

For this case I would like to have 'void' as a type parameter...

I tried to do that, compiler answered:

> Cannot use 'void' as a type parameter.

Could you please advise, what is the best solution for my case?

Just use 'Object' as parameter type and return null in function?

Is there something better?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's an unfortunate fact that `GenericType<void>` is not possible, unlike functional languages with `unit` type where you can do that easily.

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice is to create a separate non-generic type for this case.

EDIT: For example:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    public abstract void MyFunc();
}
```

Depending on how you use them, you may want to make them share an interface or base class.

Comment: could you give example based on OP's code? i am not sure i understood.

Comment: Even if they has similar interface, I won't be able to include T MyFunc() in this interface as 'MyBaseClass' knows nothing about '<T>'. and as a result, I won't be able to call this 'MyFunc' in 'polymorphic' way.

Comment: @Budda: You can't call it "polymorphically" at all.  It is not possible to call a function at compile-time if you don't know whether it returns a value.

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value at all, you could make both classes implement a common interface with a `void MyFunc()` and implement it explicitly in the generic version.

Answer (score 0):

You could typedef a "_void" to short int or something like that and use that for readability purposes. (and just return 0).

Comment: C# does not support typedefs.  You could create  a `struct Nothing { }`

Comment: class Nothing - probably is a good idea. Why this isn't an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge smell. Whatever is going on that you have defined a generic class that has a method that is returning objects and you want to derive from that class and not return anything suggests that something is very wrong. It's very likely that this method is doing something different in various overloads (some overloads are saving to a database, and some overloads are sending a job to the printer, and some overloads are constructing an object, or whatever) and that's bad design.

Please elaborate on your use case but my gut feeling is that a redesign is the best solution to your problem ("Doc, it hurts when I do this." "Then stop doing that.")

Comment: I got you point. To be clear let's consider example of 2 methods: Create (that save some object in DB and returns it's ID), and Delete (that receives objects ID and delete it from DB). Both methods throw an exception if something fails.. There are nothing to return from the 2nd method... I have a set of such methods to be called in similar way: log input parameters, authorization section, shared exception handling block, log output parameters. So I created separate class for each 'method', each class has 'T Execute()'... Is this bad?